# Where do I get HM "Rock Smash" to get through Rusturf Tunnel in Pokemon Omega Ruby/Alpha Sapphire (GEN VI)?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I have reached the part where I have to go through the Rusturf Tunnel and there are boulders that are breakable. The NPC that said he was digging the tunnel by himself said the rocks are too hard and he can't get through and when I walked closer to them, the player mentioned "if only I could smash these rocks".

Where can I acquire Rock Smash?

Comment: They were obtained much later in the game (at least after getting 2 badges and getting them in Verdanturf Town) from the other side of the Rusturf tunnel. I guess that part's been kept the same. Still jealous that you guys already have it before EU systems >~<

Comment: I read that you get it later in game in original Ruby/Sapphire, but right now, it seems like I **have to** go through the cave, unless I'm missing something... Maybe I should look up original RSE walkthrough for that part, heh

Comment: Well, in the original one, you had to get the first badge, then visit the president who will tell you to go deliver a mail to Steven in Dewford town's cave. To go there, you would go south of Petalburg woods to see Mr Briney who will take you there on his boat. And you get the 2nd badge in Dewford town.

Comment: @Jerry you are right, as I was skipping through the quest text, I saw "cave" and thought it was about the tunnel. I didn't think I'd have to actually walk *back* towards the previous towns, because that's not how it usually is, but yeah, I was wrong :P

Comment: I just remembered something. There are more boulders that prevent you from getting to a desert after Mauville, so you actually need to get the 3rd badge to use Rock Smash outside battle, of course, that is if things remained the same on that aspect.

Comment: I haven't got that far yet, but so far the plot and badge mechanics seem to be exactly the same as in the original RSE games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are automatically given Rock Smash **after defeating Wally in Mauville city**, in front of the gym and you will need the Dynamo badge to use it outside of battle.

At the point described in the question, however, you don't have to go through the Rusturf tunnel yet, instead you have to go to Dewford town, south from the Rustboro city (*credit goes to @Jerry for pointing this out*).

Comment: To get to Dewford Town you need an HM surf. An HM surf is given by Wally's dad after getting the Petalburg City Gym Badge. To get this you have to get all other Gym Badges even the ones across the sea. All this stuff is really confusing me so can someone make it clear to me what I have to do first.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the mart in mauville city its the buiding right next to it on the right go inside and talk to the guy who will give you HM06 aka rock smash

Comment: This has already been said in another answer, which actually turned out to be wrong. Please keep in mind that duplicate answers are frowned upon here and subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

In Sapphire you get it from Wally's uncle, but in Ruby you get it from the guy in the house to left of the mart in Mauvile City.

Answer (score -1):

You are not given it automatically after beating Wally, you get the HM by talking to the man in the house on the right of the Pokémart. It is only usable outside of combat after beating Wally though. The word automatically made me question my game and if something went wrong.
Just wanted to clarify to other people freaking out :D

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2BuagMO00Y) shows that you do receive it automatically from Wally's uncle after defeating Wally in front of the gym.

Comment: You are probably mistaken with original ruby/sapphire; that is where you must talk with the man